# tfs 2019 Pipeline Builds Triggers only trigger if a new check-in has happened

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-server-2019

In on prem TFS 2019, I have builds that we have triggers to happen on a schedule meaning they always build at specified times during the day. What I would like to do is to not start a build if a check-in hasn't happened since the last build ran. If no check-in has happened, we really don't have a reason to build and push new code since the code hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your pipeline does not run as scheduled if there have been no code changes since the last scheduled run.

Make sure you select **Only schedule builds if the source or pipeline has changed** in your Pipeline:

[image]

Or **not** use the `always` keyword in YAML build:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#running-even-when-there-are-no-code-changes

Comment: Thanks. We recently migrated from an older version of tfs and this checkbox was not an option. It looks like all my builds have this not checked since they were migrated.

Comment: sadly the link doesn't provide an answer to the question anymore